# How can I load wasm module through node js using typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webassembly

I want to load webassembly module in my node js application however I am unable to do so. My application is using typescript.

I tried do this:

```js
import * as  tesseract from "../libs/tesseract-core.wasm"
```

the code transpiled sucessfully however I get the  following error when I execute my script:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './libs/tesseract-core'
```

Here is how the part that import the module got transpiled look like:

```js
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
require("@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm");
const chalk_1 = __importDefault(require("chalk"));
const dotenv_1 = __importDefault(require("dotenv"));
const fancy_log_1 = __importDefault(require("fancy-log"));
const fs_1 = require("fs");
const yargs_1 = __importDefault(require("yargs"));
const helpers_1 = require("yargs/helpers");
// import library
// import { TorWindow } from "./Crawler";
const Crawler_1 = require("./Crawler/Crawler");
const WorldMarket_1 = require("./Crawler/WorldMarket");
dotenv_1.default.config();
```

I tried running changing the module type to a esnext module in the package .json  however it caused me more error! here is the error node js gave me(and yes I setted the options so typescript is transpilling to use import isntead of require):

```js
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
node:internal/process/esm_loader:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\vince\project\js\darknet-drug-crawler\dist\Crawler\Crawler' imported from C:\Users\vince\project\js\darknet-drug-crawler\dist\index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:323:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:758:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:869:11)
    at Loader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:86:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:230:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:57:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:56:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```